# Why is WebElement.isDisplayed() giving me a NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to check for the visibility of an element on the page.

I was using (psuedocode) wait.until(ExpectedCondition.visibilityOfElement(locator));

However, the default ExpectedCondition only examines the first element in the DOM matching the locator.

My locators cannot be made specific enough to only match one element (its a limitation of what I've been asked to automate, and can't be changed). But, of the the elements found, any that are displayed are fair game.

Therefore, I am using a custom ExpectedCondition, looping through the found elements, finding any that are displayed, and returning the first one found.

Code is as follows:

```java
public WebElement WaitForElementToBeVisible(WebDriver theDriver, By locator) {
    return new WebDriverWait(theDriver, STANDARD_WAIT_TIME)
            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .withTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .until((ExpectedCondition<WebElement>) driver -> {
                List<WebElement> els = driver.findElements(locator);
                for (WebElement el : els) {
                    try {
                        if (el.isDisplayed()) {
                            return el;
                        }
                    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                        /* Ignore Exception */
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        System.out.println("NullPointerException thrown");
                    }
                }
                return null;
            });
}
```

However, in some cases, the call to el.isDisplayed is throwing a NullPointerException.  I've seen in other answers that if the element is not on the page, then this will happen.  But in **this** case I know that the element is present.

I've added logs which have told me that:

1. The element is present (in fact, there are three of them)
2. isDisplayed is called on all three elements
3. All three elements throw the NullPointerException

Additionally, since it waits for 5 seconds for the element to be displayed, I have plenty of time to look and see that, yes, the element does seem to be displayed.

If we remove the catch block, the stack trace of the NullPointerException is as follows (Only the last line, because everything else is company specific, and my boss doesn't want me to share it):

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.isDisplayed(RemoteWebElement.java:323)
```

And that trace leads to:

```java
public boolean isDisplayed() {
  Object value = execute(DriverCommand.IS_ELEMENT_DISPLAYED, ImmutableMap.of("id", id))
      .getValue();
  try {
    return (Boolean) value;
  } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
    throw new WebDriverException("Returned value cannot be converted to Boolean: " + value, ex);
  }
}
```

The error is thrown by the return statement, so for whatever reason the execute command is returning null.

I believe these are the relevant sections of the pom file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Any assistance in debugging this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn' there a Expected Condition of "visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy" that would be useful to you?

Comment: Unfortunately, that one won't work.  It waits for every matching element to be visible, but in my case the issue is that I know some of them might be invisible.

Comment: Have you tried a Java `stream` and `filter`? e.g. https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/. I don't have an IDE right now but you should be able to do something like `List<WebElement> els = driver.findElements(locator).stream().filter(e -> e.isDisplayed()).collect(Collectors.toList());`. `els` would then contain any web elements that are displayed that match your locator. From there you can use `els.get(0)` to get the first displayed element.

Comment: @JeffC Just tried it, and unfortunately the problem persists.  The NullPointerException is still getting thrown as soon as isDisplayed is called by the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying issue appears to be a bug in version 77 of ChromeDriver.

Salesforce, which is what I am running this on, is modifying the constructor of the built-in AsyncFunction object, which is causing all of Selenium's Javascript calls to fail, not just isDisplayed.

It should be fixed in version 78 of Chrome/ChromeDriver.

Reference to bug and answer:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3103#c6